# Using string vector in map

Tags: c++, string, vector, dictionary

I have a map with string key and the second atribute should be vector.

Declaration:

```
map <string, vector<string> > Subjects;
```

and then when I want to use it for adding values.

```
Subjects[s] = new vector<string>;
Subjects[s].push_back(n);
```

s and n are strings. I got error just for the first line. It says `error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::mapped_type {aka std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >}’ and ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >*’)` . I tried to give pointer of vector to map, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Your value type is not a pointer, hence `new vector<string>` is redundant, the operation `Subjects[s]` will already construct the vector correctly - if it did not exist at key `s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

value of `Subjects` type is not a pointer, you can't allocate `new` to it.

if `n` is string type, just call:

```
map <string, vector<string> > Subjects;

std::string n("hello");

Subjects[s].push_back(n);
```

Edit:

To print this value from map, you need to find the element in map then iterator the vector.

```
auto it = Subjects.find(s);

if (it != Subjects.end())
{
    auto& vIt = it->second;

    for (auto elem : vIt)
    {
        cout << elem << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to print this value from map? what should I do?

Comment: You need to iterator through the map then iterator through iterator through vector.